# How to manage torando's buffer

Tags: python-3.x, http, websocket, backend, tornado

I have a tornado WebSocketHandler which I am using to send a message to my frontend. The problem is that whenever I have a slow connection to the device from where the data is being sent, I get a rather big memory leak (100mb/s). It also shows that from 190 messages that I send, 12 of them are received by frontend. Apparently, the memory leak issue is coming from the lost messages in buffer. Is there any way to manage the tornado buffer? either flushing it to avoid memory leak or keep sending the data from buffer as the receiving ends when all messages are sent from the backend (but not all are received).

I should mention that when I am connected to the device via an ethernet cable there is no memory leak and all the messages are being received.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "manage the buffer" but what helped me is setting:
`websocket_ping_interval` and `websocket_ping_timeout`.
(Without seeing the code it is difficult to suggest anything else.)